# UITableView in UITableView, populated with a JSON array of strings and arrays

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, json, uitableview

i have a JSON array that looks something like this:

JSON [@"name", roomArray, dueDate]

roomArray is an array of rooms (room1, room2, room3 etc)

each room is an array of tasks.

the taskArray is an array of task objects (task obj has a nameString, asigneeString and a status(bool))

I would like to have a UITableView where each cell has its textLabel set to JSON(@"name")

when you click a cell, it will send with it, the taskArray and dueDate and open another UITableView.

This UITableview will be split into sections named after the rooms. and the sections made of cells with a title of taskArray(nameString). a subtitle of the assignee, and a UISwitch set to status(bool).

Is all this possible? or is it a completely wrong approach?

but the real question is, how do i send the roomArray with tasks to the next UITableView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your 'real' question:

Define a property of type NSArray in the 2nd ViewController (the destination VC)
set the property in your prepareForSegue-method (if you are using storyboards):

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
destinationVC.tasksArray = (NSArray *)[roomArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

or in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath-method (if you don't use storyboards):

```
destinationVC.tasksArray = (NSArray *)[roomArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Comment: Thanks, solution 1 was just what i needed